# Python - SQLAlchemy multiple sessions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working on a system which uses SQLAlchemy to read/write to a MySQL database. I have a Factory which makes multiple repositories each one with his own session. I read the documentation os SQLAlchemy and it states that one session should not be used by different processes.

I cannot use same session as it the code will run on different machines.

My question is, is it a good practice to make different sessions? Will it have concurrency problems or races?

Example:
If i have 2 sessions writing multiple records to the db, and have a collision of a record. Will the session.commit() abort everything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLAlchemy sessions are light-weight objects so no trouble to create many sessions, and you have to use multiple sessions when you use multiple processes or multiple threads because a session cannot be shared between processes nor threads.

If there is a collision between 2 sessions, then the collision will be raised on session.commit or session autocommit depending on session configuration.

It's better to use sessions with transactions to ensure atomicity property:

```py
session = get_session()
with session.begin():
    session.add(db_obj0)
    session.add(db_obj1)
```

both `db_obj0` and `db_obj1` will be created or none.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not using transactions as i need to make sure in the best way possible that everything is written on the db, if it fails i want the least number of objects to not be created. Example, i'm sniffing packets and storing them.

Comment: FYI that modern implementations don't need `session.begin()`: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.begin